# Use hydra with evil motions

Tags: evil, hydra

I'm trying to use a hydra to dispatch among a selection of motions. See this minimal example:

```el
(defhydra hydra/test (:color blue)
  "This is a test hydra"
  ("n" evil-next-line))

(evil-define-motion hydra/test/motion-proxy (&rest args)
  (hydra/test/body))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-RET") #'hydra/test/motion-proxy)
```

Unfortunately, this motion does not compose with evil operators. For example, <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>M-RET</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> does move to the next line, but *does not* delete any text.

How can I work around this?

Comment: This question should be upvoted if only for the title :-)

Comment: If you are interested, the [key-guide](https://github.com/dalanicolai/emacs-key-guide) library can be used to list available options after pressing some `evil operator key`. Unfortunately, I did not find time to add more explanations after (partly) creating the 'development notes' (i.e. the github README). The difference with which-key is that you can custom 'design' the pop-up. A difference with hydra is that hydra uses its own keymap.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately i think this cannot work. evil commands like `d` (`evil-delete`) manually read a key sequence to obtain a motion, bypassing emacs' normal key maps.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I'd need to advise `evil-delete‘ to make it work. :P

Comment: i am not sure that will work; i think evil commands evaluate the motions themselves.